# How to train a Keras model for two different training set and different cost functions at the same time

Tags: keras, training-data, loss-function

I am trying to train a CNN based on two different sets of training data. For the training data sets A and B, I want to optimize cost functions Cost_A and Cost_B, respectively.
I want to make sure that during training the model parameters change in a direction that both loss functions are optimized at he same time.

Anyone has any idea how to implement it in Keras?

PS: I am not looking for a code! just a hint would be enough!

Comment: Hello and welcome on SO :) You need to make it easier for people to help you as they cannot just write the script for you. For example, consider narrowing your question down to more specific problems like "how to optimize two cost functions" or "how to instanciate a CNN in Keras". Note that it is likely that the answer to these specific question already lie somewhere else on this website ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Alternate minibatches

One option is to alternate training - run a minibatch of set A (using e.g. [train_on_batch](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#train_on_batch)) with cost function A, run a minibatch of set B with cost function B.

### Conditional cost function

Another option is to have a 'conditional' cost function. In essence, you could add to your inputs (making a multi-input model) a new variable X which is set to 1 for every sample from A and 0 for every sample from B. Then you can set that your cost function is `Cost_A*X + Cost_B*(1-X)`, which will ignore the "wrong" cost function for each item. Then you can just train on both datasets at once.